# Можно ли так сказать?

Tags: грамотная-речь

выбрать между яблоком и бананом. или лучше "выбрать из яблока и банана"? мне и то, и то режет слух. подскажите,плз

Answer (score 3):

Выбрать  яблоко или банан, сделать выбор между яблоком и бананом.